# Using Laravel migrations with AWS Redshift database

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, database-migration, amazon-redshift

I am using Laravel 5.3. I can connect successfully to my Redshift database.

However I discovered that the Laravel migrations feature does not work with Redshift because Laravel creates a 'migration' table within the schema which has a 'serial' type column. Redshift does not support the 'serial' type.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 7 ERROR:  Column
>   "migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial". (SQL: create table
>   "migrations" ("id" serial primary key not null,      "migration"
>   varchar(255) not null, "batch" integer not null))
>
> ```
>                                                                                                           [PDOException]
> ```
>
> SQLSTATE[0A000]: Feature not supported: 7 ERROR:  Column
>   "migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial".

Is there anyway around this so that I can use migrations with Redshift?

Answer (score 2):

For **Laravel 8.***

`migrations` table can be stored in a different database (e.g. MySQL) which has to be configured as the default connection in `config/database.php` (or `DB_CONNECTION` environment variable).

Create `migrations` table:

```
php artisan migrate:install --database=mysql
```

...where `mysql` is the name of connection.

Then in Redshift migrations you need to specify a connection explicitly:

```php
class CreateRedshiftTable extends Migration
{
    protected $connection = 'redshift';
}
```

Then run `php artisan migrate` and each migration will use specified connection. This approach has limitations though as Laravel `pgsql` driver doesn't support Redshift specific features.